# Import xml files in to the neo4j?

Tags: xml, import, neo4j

Visualizing XML files as a Graph Using Neo4j

**Create nodes and relationships from XML data files**

Does Neo4j get import the XML files to create nodes and relationships? if yes, how can i achieve it?
How to load XML files into neo4j database?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The APOC procedure [apoc.load.xml](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_load_xml) can be used to import XML data.